# Cannot convert lambda expression to inteded delegate type

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm trying to update a field in a mongodb database, but I'm getting the following error:

> Cannot convert lambda expression to intended delegate type because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type

I use the following function:

```
List<Items> items= _pat.Find(s => s.Token == data[0]).ToList();

_logs.UpdateOneAsync(s => s.item_id == items[0].item_id
    && s.Date == DateTime.Parse(data[1]),
    s => s.Status = data[2]);
```

But at the update part of the function, at `s => s.Status = data[2]`, I get the error.

How would I update `s.Status` if not via this way?

`UpdateOneAsync` is defined as:

```
Task<UpdateResult> UpdateOneAsync(FilterDefinition<TDocument> filter, 
    UpdateDefinition<TDocument> update, UpdateOptions options = null,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken));
```

Comment: What is the signature of `UpdateOneAsync`?

Comment: The full signature is `Task<UpdateResult> UpdateOneAsync(FilterDefinition<TDocument> filter, UpdateDefinition<TDocument> update, UpdateOptions options = null, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken));`, a part of the package `MongoDB.Driver`

Comment: @Unseptium, since you are using what appear to be custom delegate types (`FilterDefinition<>` and `UpdateDefinition<>`, can you please provide the definitions for those as well?

Comment: ```<summary> Base class for updates.  </summary>
<typeparam name="TDocument">The type of the document.</typeparam>
public abstract class UpdateDefinition<TDocument>```

Comment: Right, so that's not a delegate... you're providing a lambda expression as the argument (`s => s.Status = data[2]`) - how would you expect that to be converted to an `UpdateDefinition<TDocument>`?

Comment: To be very honest Jon, I'm still very much learning C#, so I hadn't thought about if that would or would not work. Looking at the signatures the next time I get these kinds of errors is a clever thing to do, I'll keep it in mind! Thank you for your patience and advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signature of `UpdateOneAsync` is:

```
Task<UpdateResult> UpdateOneAsync(FilterDefinition<TDocument> filter, 
    UpdateDefinition<TDocument> update, UpdateOptions options = null,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken));
```

Thus, you need to use UpdateDefinition instead of a lambda function.
So instead of `s => s.Status = data[2]`, use `Builders<Items>.Update.Set(p => p.Status, data[2])`.